# Android: Can JetPlayer control the tempo (or speed) of MIDI file?

Tags: android, mobile

I want to build a music app which play MIDI file and can control the speed.

I know that JatPlayer can play MIDI file, but can JetPlayer control the speed?

Thank you very much.

Best Regards,
Bloom
Bangkok, THAILAND